# When making multiple attacks, does advantage from being unseen apply to all attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, stealth, advantage-and-disadvantage, multiattack

When you dual-wield or multiattack somebody who can't see you, are both/all attacks with advantage? We are using facing rules, so attacking silently from behind is a common situation I expect to bring this up.

To clarify, I'm not talking about sneak attack here. I know that you can only sneak once per turn. I'm just wondering if I jump somebody from the shadows and I hit them with multiple attacks, if they are all with advantage. Are they?

If advantage is denied on second attack because the opponent wouldn't be unaware anymore, or would turn and defend, does losing advantage happen even in case the first attack (*with* advantage) missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The first attack has advantage, the rest don't**

Let's assume that you sneak up on somebody without being noticed with a good stealth check. You are effectively invisible at this point. And as such, you have advantage on attack rolls. So the first attack has advantage.

After that attack though, regardless of a hit or miss, you are no longer hidden. So, you no longer can be considered "effectively invisible" and your attack rolls no longer have advantage. So, attacks after the first no longer have advantage.

However, by sneaking up on somebody and attacking them, you most likely have surprised them as well. So, you get to take an additional turn in combat before they can take any actions at all.

Comment: the additional turn in combat would still not grant any advantage because you revealed your presence

Comment: @Ghilteras Correct, and the post doesn't suggest otherwise. It's worth noting though.

Comment: Isn't being hidden a actually a step above being invisible, the difference being that an invisible creature's location is known where as being hidden hides your location. Doesn't this mean that when you do attack while hidden and your location is revealed, you become effectively invisible? Imagine a goblin hiding in the darkness and shooting you with a bow. Yeah, when it attacks you can hear the twang and maybe see the arrow fly out, but all you can gleam is where the attack came from, you cant see the goblin without searching right?

Answer (score 3):

From the PHB p.195:

> When a creature can’t see you, you have advantage on 
>   attack rolls against it.

And from p.177:

> When you try to hide, make a Dexterity (Stealth) check. **Until 
>   you are discovered or you stop hiding**, that check’s total is 
>   contested by the Wisdom (Perception) check of any creature 
>   that actively searches for signs of your presence.

The first attack has advantage, after that "you are discovered or you stop hiding" so the subsequent attacks do not.

Exception: if you have the skulker feat and miss with your first *ranged* attack.

Comment: I think the rules for Unseen Attackers goes on to say something about revealing your location right? If someone knows your location does that mean you are no longer hidden? Isn't being hidden to do with being unseen and unheard? For example being invisible means you can be heard and your location is known, so even if people know your location then so long as you dont make sound you are even less visible than someone who is invisible.